# Group, Sort, and then Merge to a Observable Collection?

Tags: c#, sorting, observablecollection

I have a List of Items that have a "DisplayOrder" property. This can either have NULL or int value. If it has int value, it has priority and should be in the 1st group of the Observable Collection. Items in the 1st group are also sorted by DisplayOrder.

If it is NULL, then it belongs to the 2nd group, sorted alphabetically.

The 1st group and 2nd group are then combined for a Main Items Collection Observable Collection which I bind to a ListView.

This is my current code though I am worried if there is a much optimal way of doing it.

```
var MainItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<MainItemViewModel>();
var ItemsWithProperty = new ObservableCollection<MainItemViewModel>();
var ItemsWithNullProperty = new ObservableCollection<MainItemViewModel>();

foreach (var item in DataObject.MainItems)
{
    if (item.DisplayOrder == null)
        ItemsWithNullProperty.Add(new MainItemViewModel(item));
    else
        ItemsWithProperty.Add(new MainItemViewModel(item));
}

ItemsWithProperty = new ObservableCollection<MainItemViewModel>(ItemsWithProperty.OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder));
ItemsWithNullProperty = new ObservableCollection<MainItemViewModel>(ItemsWithNullProperty.OrderBy(c => c.Title));

//Add those with priorities first sorted by DisplayOrder 1,2,3,4
foreach (var c in ItemsWithProperty)
{
    MainItemCollection.Add(c);
}

//Add those without priority sorted Alphabetically
foreach (var c in ItemsWithNullProperty)
{
    MainItemCollection.Add(c);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When doing things like this, you don't need all those intermediate `ObservableCollection`s - you can use the appropriate data structures like array, list, dictionary, hash set etc. or Linq queries. In this particular case, the whole procedure can be reduced to something like this

```
var MainItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<MainItemViewModel>(DataObject.MainItems
    .OrderBy(item => item.DisplayOrder ?? int.MaxValue)
    .ThenBy(item => item.DisplayOrder == null ? item.Title : string.Empty)
);
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I ended up using a Custom Sort Ordering function to optimize performance.

Answer (score 1):

Get the items with DisplayOrder=null & order them by Title:

```
ItemsWithNullProperty=DataObject.MainItems.Where(x=>x.DisplayOrder==null).OrderBy(o=>o.Title).ToList();
```

Get the items with DisplayOrder(all items except the above query) & order them by DisplayOrder:

```
ItemsWithProperty= DataObject.MainItems.Except(ItemsWithNullProperty).OrderBy(o=>o.DisplayOrder).ToList();
```

Fill the data in MainCollection:

```
var allItems = MainItemCollection.Concat(ItemsWithProperty)
                                    .Concat(ItemsWithNullProperty)
                                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thansk TechieBee. I ended up using a Custom Sort Ordering function to optimize performance.

Comment: @Water Thats great !!

Answer (score 1):

I feel that this is a pretty common scenario.
There is a sorted ObservableCollection bound to some XAML UI, and once more data is available UI needs to be updated without full refresh.
Whenever new ObservableCollection is created like in suggestions above, all items will be rebound and therefore UI fully updated.

I'm surprised that there are no library methods to achieve this. Here is the solution I've came up with. Hope someone might find it useful.

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void MergeSortedListIntoSortedObservableCollection<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> destination, IList<T> list, Func<T, T, int> compareFunc)
    {
        int dest_index = 0;
        int list_index = 0;

        while (list_index < list.Count)
        {
            if (dest_index >= destination.Count)
            {
                destination.Add(list[list_index]);
                list_index++;
                dest_index++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (compareFunc(destination[dest_index], list[list_index]) > 0)
                {
                    destination.Insert(dest_index, list[list_index]);
                    list_index++;
                    dest_index++;
                }
                else
                {
                    dest_index++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```